# WPF Designer vs Qt Designer and Widget Parenting

Tags: wpf, qt, widget, designer

I'm an experienced C++/Qt developer but a newbie C#/WPF developer, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something with the Visual Studio 2010 WPF designer.

In Qt, all widgets have a parent. I found this concept very useful both when building GUI programmatically and in the designer. From what I remember from Qt desginer (unfortunately my new company doesn't support Qt), you could easily drag widgets around and they get re-parented correctly. If the designer somehow got confused, then you could just reset the parent to whatever you needed in the properties box. I find the analogous ideas in WPF difficult to execute.

In the Visual Studio Designer, when I drag widgets around, they only sometimes get the right parent. More often than not, I have to go to the xaml and cut-and-paste the widget I was writing into a different part of the xaml so that it gets the right parent. I understand that the DOM tree of xaml nicely parallels the widget parent tree, but I found that was much more explicit in Qt.

So, my question is: is this cut-and-paste approach to re-parenting in WPF xaml the best you can do or are there some nice designer tips-and-tricks that I am missing?

Note: this question obviously doesn't apply when building GUI programmatically.

Comment: Maybe I'm alone, but I really never use the designer, I prefer directly work in xaml, it seems strange, but it is really more productive.

Comment: I may end up having to work this way. My feeling was that when building a large and complicated custom widget, one would eventually have to get one's hands dirty and do the final details in xaml, this I am happy with. But I was hoping that, at least initially, you could lay out all your subwidgets in the designer to save time. I've found this to be true on the first pass, but then when I want to move things around, I run into this re-parenting issue.

Comment: if you read some good book on xaml, you will find it more powerful than the plain designer. Then if you need some fancy skin, maybe you will try Expression Blend, but this is another story...

Comment: I think you're right, after some time xaml does become second nature, and I'm happy with the cut and paste method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this boils down to a lacking designer in VS2010. Personally I use the designer for WPF as a view on how the GUI will look, and then hand code most of my XAML. I almost never actually DO anything in the designer such as drag an element or such.

To answer your question, the cut-paste in xaml approach you mention  is in my experience the most efficient way to "re-parenting" elements.